# Automapper - AutoMapperMappingException and NullReferenceException for nested type

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a Tag class and a corresponding TagDto class which I want to map from Tag to TagDto.

Due to my usage of EF Core I have a Collection to a class called MoneyItemTag which represents a many-to-many relationship.

Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class MoneyItemBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ItemText { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public MoneyItemType MoneyItemType { get; protected set; }

    public ICollection<MoneyItemTag> MoneyItemTags { get; set; }
}

public class MoneyItemTag
{
    public int MoneyItemId { get; set; }

    public MoneyItemBase MoneyItem { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MoneyItemTag> MoneyItemTags { get; set; }
}

 [Fact]
    public void Tag_TagDto_Mapping()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            //cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Tag, TagDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.MoneyItems, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.MoneyItemTags.Select(x => x.MoneyItem)));
            cfg.CreateMap<MoneyItemBase, MoneyItemBaseDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Tags, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.MoneyItemTags.Select(y => y.Tag.TagName).ToList()));
        });

        MoneyItemTag mo = new MoneyItemTag();
        mo.MoneyItem = new SingleIncome() { Id = 2, ItemText = "test", Active = false, DueDate = DateTime.Now, Amount = 33 };
        mo.MoneyItemId = 2;
        var mit = new List<MoneyItemTag>() { mo };

        Tag tag = new Tag() { TagId = 2, TagName = "test", MoneyItemTags = mit };
        mo.TagId = 2;
        mo.Tag = tag;

        var dto = Mapper.Map<TagDto>(tag);

        Assert.NotNull(dto);
```

And this relationship is causing some trouble. When I run the following test or when I want make the mapping in my Asp.Net core application, I get the following exception:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Tag -> TagDto
HouseholdBook.Data.Model.Tag -> HouseholdBook.Dto.TagDto

Type Map configuration:
Tag -> TagDto
HouseholdBook.Data.Model.Tag -> HouseholdBook.Dto.TagDto

Property:
MoneyItems
---- AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
MoneyItemBase -> MoneyItemBaseDto
HouseholdBook.Data.Model.MoneyItemBase -> HouseholdBook.Dto.MoneyItemBaseDto

Type Map configuration:
MoneyItemBase -> MoneyItemBaseDto
HouseholdBook.Data.Model.MoneyItemBase -> HouseholdBook.Dto.MoneyItemBaseDto

Property:
Id
-------- System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an 
instance of an object.
```

What is wrong here? I cannot see from the exception message what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I figured out what was wrong.
`MoneyItemBase` is abstract and abstract classes cannot be instantiated directly.

I ended up with mapping my class hierarchy using the `Include` method of `CreateMap`.
Below is a snippet from my example.

```
CreateMap<MoneyItemBase, MoneyItemBaseDto>()
        .Include<SingleIncome, SingleMoneyItemDto>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Tags, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.MoneyItemTags.Select(y => y.Tag.TagName).ToList()));

CreateMap<SingleIncome, SingleMoneyItemDto>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create explicit mappings for all the nested classes:
`cfg.CreateMap<HouseholdBook.Data.Model.Tag, HouseholdBook.Dto.TagDto>();`

`opts => opts.MapFrom()` is used when members names in source and target doesn't match, it doesn't register map between these types.